# Using js libraries added by Libman in Razor Pages solution

Tags: asp.net-core, three.js, razor-pages, libman

I'm new to Razor Pages development and I have a problem with using `Three.js` (added by Libman) in my project. I added Three.js using Libman (default solution config, never used libman before, but it look like packages are in right place):
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrpG4.png)

And then included in main layout view (`_Layout.cshtml`):

```
<script src="~/lib/three/src/Three.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/three/examples//jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

but errors appear in F12 console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Errors points out to both included previously files: `Three.js:1` and `OrbitControl.js:1`

Libman content:

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "defaultProvider": "cdnjs",
  "libraries": [
    {
      "provider": "cdnjs",
      "library": "p5.js@1.9.0",
      "destination": "wwwroot/lib/p5.js/"
    },
    {
      "provider": "unpkg",
      "library": "font-awesome@4.7.0",
      "destination": "wwwroot/lib/font-awesome/"
    },
    {
      "provider": "unpkg",
      "library": "three@0.160.1",
      "destination": "wwwroot/lib/three/"
    },
  ]
}
```

One of suggestion I found is to add `type="module` but that confuses me - where to add that? I dont have `package.json` file since I'm using Libman

Does anyone knows how to solve that?

I'm expecting to configure Razor Pages with `Three.js` library in the way that would allow me to use 3D graphic in one of Pages

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Can you provide code?

Comment: Sure, I can prepare minimal solution that represents my problem - is there any build in tool on Stack where I can put solution files? Or I should make a zip and post here a link from some file share service? It most likely problem related to solution/project config than piece of code

Comment: To be honest all I did so far is to create Razor Pages solution in .net 8, added Three.js (right click on wwwroot->add client side library, source set to unpkg) and then added two js files I wanted to use to _layout.cshtml

Answer (score 0):

You add `type="module"` to the script tag:

```
<script src="~/lib/three/src/Three.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="~/lib/three/examples//jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js" type="module"></script>
```